# How create a batch to change the Workgroup?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that changes the name of the computer. Now I also want to change the Workgroup. How can I add this to the `.batch?`

This is what I have now, for changing the computer name:

```
@echo off
SET /P PCNAME=Please enter your desired PC name:
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
```

Only now I need the same for the Workgroupname.

Answer (score 0):

here is the command line

```
Wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" call joindomainorworkgroup name="[new workgroup name]
```

Comment: is there a way to do this withour the where clause, or withot using the old computername ?